# Solr's facet search returns wrong number count without query parameter

Tags: solr

I have document with 700k document.

In them, 247 document have `country:"FI"` field

I set the grouping setting and enable facet on `country` field

```
group.truncate=true&
group.ngroups=true&
group.field=ent_id&
group=true&
facet.limit=-1
```

If I have query

```
country:*
```

I have facet return FI=39 (Wrong number)

If I use query

```
country :"FI"
```

I have facet return FI=47 (Correct number)

What is the reason for this? My final goal would be a facet query that congregate all the country and their number of appearance

Comment: What do you want `country:*` to do? If you want to get all documents that have a value for country, `country:[* TO *]` is the proper way.

Comment: I want to get all document. I just use it this way for reader to easily see the differences that lead to 2 different results

Comment: If you want all documents, use `*:*` as your query.